# Что лучше для Django - хостинг или VPS?

Tags: python-3.x, django, хостинг, vps

У меня есть Django-проект, небольшой. И я вот все думаю, что лучше для него брать - хостинг или VPS. Может кто посоветует чего?

Comment: Что лучше - ездить на такси или иметь собственный автомобиль?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev аналогия - не очень :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну да, хостинг больше похож на маршрутку, которая не едет, пока бабка ругается с водителем, чей-то ребёнок орёт, заглушая шансон, и ещё кто-то топчется по ногам, а VPS'ка - это автомобиль, который ремонтировать придётся самому :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вот теперь топ :), а главное акценты расставлены :)

Comment: То есть все-таки VPS...

Comment: Есть даже шаред-хостинги для Django - все зависит от целей использования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первую очередь зависит от ваших навыков, потребностей и ресурсов.

**VPS**

Достоинства:

1. Возможность установки любого ПО, требуемого для вашего сайта (в частности: любые приложения и библиотеки);
2. Собственный ip-адрес. Кроме очевидных достоинств этого пункта, такая вещь, как личный ip повышает защиту ваших данных;
3. Возможность оперативно распределять ресурсы сервера между проектами. Также вы можете разместить любое количество проектов на сервере.

Недостатки:

1. Требуются хотя бы начальные навыки администрирования таких серверов;
2. Большая стоимость по сравнению с хостингом.

**Хостинг**

Достоинства:

1. Не требуется практически никаких навыков управления сервером. Разберётся абсолютно любой и очень быстро;
2. Меньшая стоимость (зависит от хостера).

Недостатки:

1. Ограниченность в количестве размещённых проектов, а также невозможность распределять ресурсы между ними;
2. Общий ip-адрес. Если кто-то накосячит, по шапке получат все.

**Резюмирую**

Таким образом, только вам решать, что для вас лучше, ориентируясь на свои навыки и требуемые ресурсы, но мой личный совет - VPS.